# How is this algorithm average case derived?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, search-algorithms, average-case

For a simple linear search on an unsorted list my textbook says the following:

> To determine the average case, you add the number of iterations required to find the target at each possible position and divide the sum by n.  Thus, the algorithm performs (n + n - 1 + n -2 + ... + 1)/n, or (n + 1)/2 iterations.

The code example he uses is this:

> ```
> def sequentialSearch(target, lyst):
>     """Returns the position of the target item if found, or -1 otherwise."""
>     position = 0
>     while position < len(lyst):
>         if target == lyst[position]:
>             return position
>         position += 1
>     return False
> ```

I'm having trouble understanding how he is deriving (n + 1)/2 from the above?

Comment: Hint: What do you think is the sum of that first expression?  Think "Gauss sum".

Comment: Our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) may help. You just analyse the algorithm for "find `lyst[i]`" and average over all `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum $n+(n-1)+\dots + 3+2+1$ evaluates to $n(n+1)/2$ (it's the so-called Gauss sum).  Now divide by $n$, you and get $(n+1)/2$.